# What are some good reflecting undergrounds for product photography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, product-photography

I'm searching something like acryl but cheaper if possible. Are there any good alternatives? Something like this: [Google image search for "reflecting undergrounds"](https://www.google.de/search?q=reflecting+undergrounds&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju8ueSm5rKAhUGmg4KHXWeBKMQ_AUIBygB&biw=1366&bih=667)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any good alternatives?

There are all kinds of reflective surfaces available. Drive over to the nearest home center and look around; you'll find:

- window glass
- sheets of various plastics such as Lexan
- metals like stainless steel, aluminum, and copper
- plastic laminate
- glass tiles and glazed ceramic tiles
- mirrored glass

For that matter, look around your home before going anywhere. Even a sheet of acetate film that's often used to wrap flowers and other products can provide a good reflective surface. Place that on a sheet of colored paper and you've got a nice shiny surface for your product to sit on.

Comment: This is a nice starting list. I would add metalic wrapping paper for gifts. And autoadhesive vynil.

Comment: You also can use the hood of your car! Well, if you do not have a car this will be more expensive...

Answer (score 1):

I use ceramic bathroom tiles every time I need to create a similar product shot.

I use all different colours for different products and use the lighting to determine the level of reflection needed for any given shot.